# TCP - What if client call close() before server accept()

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

In C/C++, if client and server finished 3-way handshake and this connection was sitting in server's backlog (listening queue). Before server calls `accept()`, what gonna happen if client calls `close()`. Will this connection get removed from backlog?

The real world situation is that, server sometimes is too busy to accept every connection immediately. So there will be some connections waiting in backlog. The client has a timeout for the first response from server. If the timeout happens, it will call `close()` then retry or whatever. At this moment, I am wondering if the backlog of server will remove the connection from backlog.

Please share your idea. Appriciate it!

Comment: Related : [TCP: What happens when client connects, sends data and disconnects before accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328803/)

Comment: The port of the BSD network stack in eCos 2 had an annoying tendency to leak the socket's file handle when you did this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a client calls `close()`, the clients protocol stack will send a FIN to indicate that the client is done sending, and will wait for the server to send a FIN,ACK back to the client (which won't happen before the server accepts the connection, as we shall see), and then the client will ACK that.  This would be a normal termination of a TCP connection.

However, since a TCP connection consists of two more or less independent streams, sending a FIN from the client really is only a statement that the client is done sending data (this is often referred to as "half closed"), and is not actually a request at the TCP protocol level to close the connection (although higher level protocols often will interpret it that way, but they can only do so after the connection has been accepted and they have had a read return 0 bytes in order to learn that the client is done writing). The server can still continue to send data, but since the client has called `close()`, it is no longer possible for this data to be delivered to the client application. If the server sends further data, the protocol stack on the client will respond with a reset, causing an abnormal termination of the TCP connection.  If the client actually wished to continue receiving data from the server after declaring that it was done sending data, it should do so by calling `shutdown(sock,SHUT_WR)` rather than calling `close()`.

So what this means is that the connections that time out and that are normally closed by clients will generally remain active at the server, and the server will be able to accept them, read the request, process the request, and send the reply and only then discover that the application can no longer read the reply when the reset is returned from the client. The reason I say "generally" is that firewalls, proxies, and OS protocol stacks all place limits on how long a TCP connection can remain in a half closed state, generally in violation of the relevant TCP RFCs but for "valid" reasons such as dealing with DDOS.

I think your concern is that a server that is overloaded will be further overloaded by clients timing out and retrying, which in my view is correct based on my preceding explanation.  In order to avoid this, a client timing out could set SO_LINGER to 0 prior to calling `close()` which would cause a reset to be sent to cause an immediate abnormal termination.  I would also suggest using an exponential back-off on timeout to further mitigate the impact on an overloaded server.

Comment: One point is that TCP, itself, does not have clients or servers. It establishes connections between two equal peers, and what you describe can happen from either side. The client/server concept is an application concept.

Comment: @RonMaupin agreed.  I am just using the language of the OP who has client server thing going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You amazingly predicted the DDOS that I wrongly caused by myself. And also provide the solution of exponential back-off which me and my co-worker discussed about before read your anwser. Appreiciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Once the 3way handshake is complete, the connection is in an ESTABLISHED state. On the client side, it can start sending data immediately. On the server  side, the connection is placed in a state/queue that `accept()` can then pull from so the application can use the connection (see [How TCP backlog works in Linux](http://veithen.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html)).

If the server doesn't `accept()` the connection, the connection is still ESTABLISHED, it's inbound buffer will simply fill up with whatever data the client sends, if any.

If the client disconnects before `accept()` is called, then the connection still enters the CLOSED state, and will be removed from the queue that `accept()` pulls from.  The application will never see the connection.

Comment: can you be persuaded to learn rust - we need a responsive expert in that lang , just like you are in c++ :-)

Comment: A TCP connection has a stream in each direction. When client calls `close()` it will send a FIN and the connection will be "half closed;" the TCP state diagram does not move from ESTABLISHED to CLOSED directly. Note that at a protocol level, calling `close()` is indistinguishable from shutdown(sock,SHUT_WR) which allows the client to continue to read the stream from the server.  If any data was received after the `close()`, that would trigger a RST, but the socket would have to have been accepted for this to happen.